# Attach a show button to edit text field android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to attach a show button to edittext as shown in the in the below snippets

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
        android:text="Show" />
```

This is the illustration of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Is there a way I can attach the button immediately close to the editfield?

Comment: create a  custom drawable and assign it to both..

Comment: Placing both items together in a horizontal LinearLayout would keep them both next to each other (unless there is any padding or margins).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create drawable xml for your button and edittext and set them as background...
Take a `LinearLayout` with orientation horizontal and `weightsum == 1` and put both in it

button_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
  <stroke
      android:width="1px"
      android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

edit_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <stroke
      android:width="1px"
      android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_border" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:text="Send" 
        android:background="@drawable/button_border" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using a relative layout orientation. Is it achievable with that

Comment: put this in your relative layout it will work...my parent layout is relative only..you need to assign id to linear layout also...see changes in answer

Comment: and yes do not use `<corner>` if you do not want space in both

Answer (score 0):

We use android:layout_weight="1" along with the android:layout_width="0dp" to create a flexible control. Adjust the weight number for different size ratios.

Afterwards, we use android:layout_margin on both controls so the resulting weighted size of each is equal.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```